# Python: OSError: cannot identify image file

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to run Python3 on Ubuntu, but I'm running in to some weird errors. The script can apparently not locate a file which I have confirmed exists.

Here is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 52, in <module>
    insert_text("For kunde",dir + "/" + project_num + "_signature_customer.jpg", 0)
  File "script.py", line 46, in insert_text
    insert_text(search_term, img_path, (i + 50))
  File "script.py", line 46, in insert_text
    insert_text(search_term, img_path, (i + 50))
  File "script.py", line 40, in insert_text
    img = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image(img_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/openpyxl/drawing/image.py", line 34, in __init__
    image = _import_image(img)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/openpyxl/drawing/image.py", line 18, in _import_image
    img = PILImage.open(img)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2295, in open
    % (filename if filename else fp))
OSError: cannot identify image file '/var/www/my_ip/uploads/333333_signature_customer.jpg'
```

and here is parts of the script

```
project_num = "333333"
dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

# This function places the image found at img_path 2 cells above where the search_term is found.
def insert_text(search_term, img_path, i):

  if i > 400:
    return None

  found = False

  for x in range(1 + i,51 + i):
    for y in range(1,101):
      if isinstance(ws.cell(row=x, column=y).value,str):
        if  ws.cell(row=x, column=y).value == search_term:
          img = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image(img_path)
          img.anchor = ws.cell(row=(x-2),column=y).coordinate
          ws.add_image(img)
          found = True

  if not found:
    insert_text(search_term, img_path, (i + 50))

# if os.path.isfile(dir + "/" + project_num + "_signature_ikm.jpg"):
  # insert_text("redacted Testing AS",dir + "/" + project_num + "_signature_ikm.jpg", 0)
if os.path.isfile(dir + "/" + project_num + "_signature_customer.jpg"):
  # insert_text("For kunde","signature_customer.jpg", 0)
  insert_text("For kunde",dir + "/" + project_num + "_signature_customer.jpg", 0)
```

Here is me using the LS command in the folder where the image is located

```
john_doe@1e19udt0shu6:/var/www/my_ip/uploads$ ls
333333.xlsx                    333333_signed.xlsx  node_modules       script.py       script_backup.py        signature_redacted.jpg
333333_signature_customer.jpg  redacted2.png            package-lock.json  script.py.save  signature_customer.jpg  test.py
```

The file is clearly there, but Python3 seems to disagree. Any ideas for why? Before I call insert_text(), I even confirm that the file exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file is there. It is just that PIL can not identify the format of the image file so it can not load the file. The file is not a JPEG or any other format PIL can load.

Run

```
file 333333_signature_customer.jpg
```

or look at its head

```
xxd 333333_signature_customer.jpg | head
```

to identify what type of file it actually is. (`xxd` is in the `vim` package)

Comment: It's apparently an ASCII text with very long lines, so it's an issue with my file uploading then. Thanks!